# Arrow heads pointing wrong direction when using xy-pic

Tags: latex, xypic

I'm using the xy-pic package to draw latex diagrams.  I have previously used xymatrix but for this diagram I need to specify points instead of using a matrix format.  In the following MWE I specify two points and then draw a line between them.  From the xy-pic reference manual I used `?>*' to combine two commands and then try to draw an arrow head on the end of my line.  As can be seen in the MWE the arrow head appears but is not in the same direction as the line.  I'm at wits end and would appreciate any help the community could provide.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xy
(0,0)="A",
(15,15)="B",
"A";"B"**@{.}?>*{>},
\endxy

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank Dr. Ross Moore of Macquarie University for helping me with the answer.

My original attempt of adding the arrowhead, ?>*{>}, simply added the ">" character and did not add an arrowhead.  Instead I needed to use the following line of code to change the line I drew to include an arrowhead:

```
"A";"B"**@{.}?>*@{>},
```

Michael Barr also suggested I consider the diagxy package which can be invoked using:

```
\usepackage[barr]{xy}
```